# How do I clone a java byte array?

Tags: java

I have a byte array which i want to copy/clone to avoid calling code from modifying my internal representation.

How do I clone a java byte array?

Comment: Depending on what kind of data you're storing in this `byte[]`, an immutable list that doesn't need copying may be "better".

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> #### [JLS 6.4.5 The Members of an Array Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/names.html#6.4.5)
>
> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - The `public final field length`, which contains the number of components of the array (length may be positive or zero).
> - The `public` method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name in class `Object` and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the clone method of an array type `T[]` is `T[]`.
> - All the members inherited from class `Object`; the only method of `Object` that is not inherited is its `clone` method.

Thus:

```
byte[] original = ...;
byte[] copy = original.clone();
```

Note that for array of reference types, `clone()` is essentially a *[shallow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy)*.

Also, Java doesn't have multidimensional arrays; it has array of arrays. Thus, a `byte[][]` is an `Object[]`, and is also subject to *shallow copy*.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Object copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy)
- [Java Nuts and Bolts/Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

#### Related questions

- [Deep cloning multidimensional arrays in Java… ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200387/deep-cloning-multidimensional-arrays-in-java)
- [How to effectively copy an array in java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589741/how-to-effectively-copy-an-array-in-java)
- [How to deep copy an irregular 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419858/how-to-deep-copy-an-irregular-2d-array)
- [How do I do a deep copy of a 2d array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java)

---

#### Other options

Note that `clone()` returns a *new* array object. If you simply want to copy the values from one array to an already existing array, you can use e.g. [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) (jdk 1.0+).

There's also [`java.util.Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).copyOf (jdk 1.6+) that allows you to create a copy with a different length (either truncating or padding).

#### Related questions

- [Difference between various Array copy methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697250/difference-between-various-array-copy-methods)

Comment: Nice. I swore `.clone` didn't work for arrays; I would've said `arraycopy` [like TofuBeer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208899/how-do-i-clone-a-java-byte-array/3208918#3208918)

Comment: I just like arraycopy because I don't like clone in general - broken by design :-)

Comment: @TofuBeer: yes, `clone` generally is indeed broken, but Bloch claims that Doug Lea makes an exception for arrays (http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

Answer (score 10):

System.arraycopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.length);

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I fail to see how it doesn't answer the question. You pass it the appropriate parameters and you get a copy (clone) of the array.  What am I missing?

Comment: @TofuBeer You didn't say that you need to first create an array of the same size of the source.

Answer (score 9):

It's easy, and it's a great idea to do it.

```
byte[] copy = arr.clone();
```

Note that the return type of the `clone()` method of arrays is the type of the array, so no cast is required.

Answer (score 4):

In order to avoid a possible Null Pointer Exception I use the following syntax:

```java
byte[] copy = (arr == null) ? null : arr.clone();
```