# Is there an equivalent to memcpy() in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a byte[] and would like to copy it into another byte[].  Maybe I am showing my simple 'C' background here, but is there an equivalent to memcpy() on byte arrays in Java?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You might try [`System.arraycopy`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) or make use of array functions in the [`Arrays`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class like `java.util.Arrays.copyOf`. Both should give you native performance under the hood.

Arrays.copyOf is probably favourable for readability, but was only introduced in java 1.6.

```
 byte[] src = {1, 2, 3, 4};
 byte[] dst = Arrays.copyOf(src, src.length);
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dst));
```

Comment: I think the second option is more "logical". I never understood why System.arraycopy() is where is, one of the clumsiest possible locations.

Comment: @Sinuhe - it is there for historical reasons.

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer. memcpy() does not allocate data, only copies to an existing buffer. While Arrays.copyOf() clearly allocate new memory.

Answer (score 123):

Use [System.arraycopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

```
System.arraycopy(sourceArray, 
                 sourceStartIndex,
                 targetArray,
                 targetStartIndex,
                 length);
```

Example,

```
String[] source = { "alpha", "beta", "gamma" };
String[] target = new String[source.length];
System.arraycopy(source, 0, target, 0, source.length);
```

or use [Arrays.copyOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28byte%5B%5D,%20int%29)

Example,

```
target = Arrays.copyOf(source, length);
```

`java.util.Arrays.copyOf(byte[] source, int length)` was added in JDK 1.6.

 The `copyOf()` method uses `System.arrayCopy()` to make a copy of the array, but is more flexible than `clone()` since you can make copies of parts of an array.

Comment: Arrays.copyOf() also allocates memory.  in your example if you change String[] target = new String[4]; and then target = Arrays.copyOf() it creates a  new target which is a String[3].  Not the memcopy behavior.

Comment: Arrays.copyOf internally uses System.arraycopy which is a native method.

Answer (score 12):

If you just want an exact copy of a one-dimensional array, use [`clone()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()).

```
byte[] array = { 0x0A, 0x01 };
byte[] copy = array.clone();
```

For other array copy operations, use `System.arrayCopy`/`Arrays.copyOf` as [Tom suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329163/is-there-an-equivalent-to-memcpy-in-java/3329178#3329178).

*In general, `clone` should be avoided, but this is an exception to the rule.*

Comment: See also more detail in the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208899/how-do-i-clone-a-java-byte-array .

Answer (score 5):

You can use [System.arrayCopy](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)). It copies elements from a source array to a destination array. The Sun implementation uses hand-optimized assembler, so this is fast.

Answer (score 4):

Java actually does have something just like memcpy(). The Unsafe class has a copyMemory() method that is essentially identical to memcpy(). Of course, like memcpy(), it provides no protection from memory overlays, data destruction, etc. It is not clear if it is really a memcpy() or a memmove(). It can be used to copy from actual addresses to actual addresses or from references to references. Note that if references are used, you must provide an offset (or the JVM will die ASAP).

Unsafe.copyMemory() works (up to 2 GB per second on my old tired PC). Use at your own risk. Note that the Unsafe class does not exist for all JVM implementations.

Comment: sorry for going all pet sematary on this ancient thread, but could you given me an example on how to do that with an array of references. And is it faster for small amounts of data (like 1-4 MB) or just worthy in case of larger data like the 2GB you mentioned?

Comment: Using the `sun.misc.Unsafe` class is considered a bad practice "hack" b/c it's a *private* package class. In addition, starting in Java 9, it won't be available anymore, so trying to use this class is the same as begging for your code to break unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [System.arraycopy](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy)

Answer (score 2):

When you are using JDK 1.5+ You should use

```
System.arraycopy()
```

Instead of

```
Arrays.copyOfRange()
```

Beacuse Arrays.copyOfRange() wasn't added until JDK 1.6.So you might get

```
Java - “Cannot Find Symbol” error
```

when calling Arrays.copyOfRange in that version of JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Use [byteBufferViewVarHandle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#byteBufferViewVarHandle(java.lang.Class,java.nio.ByteOrder)) or byteArrayViewVarHandle.

This will let you copy an array of "longs" directly to an array of "doubles" and similar with something like:

```
public long[] toLongs(byte[] buf) {
    int end = buf.length >> 3;
    long[] newArray = new long[end];
    for (int ii = 0; ii < end; ++ii) {
        newArray[ii] = (long)AS_LONGS_VH.get(buf, ALIGN_OFFSET + ii << 3);
    }
}

private static final ALIGN_OFFSET = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[0]).alignmentOffset(8); 
private static final VarHandle AS_LONGS_VH = MethodHandles.byteArrayViewVarHandle(long[].class, ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
```

This will let you do the bit hacking like:

```
float thefloat = 0.4;
int floatBits;
_Static_assert(sizeof theFloat == sizeof floatBits, "this bit twiddling hack requires floats to be equal in size to ints");
memcpy(&floatBits, &thefloat, sizeof floatBits);
```

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Java does not have an equivalent to `memcpy`. Java has an equivalent to `memmove` instead.

> If the src and dest arguments refer to the same array object, then the copying is performed as if the components at positions srcPos through srcPos+length-1 were first copied to a temporary array with length components and then the contents of the temporary array were copied into positions destPos through destPos+length-1 of the destination array.

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

It is very likely `System.arraycopy` will never have the same performance as `memcpy` if `src` and `dest` refer to the same array. Usually this will be fast enough though.